# When I install chinese language my language sport hang (GUI)?

Tags: gnome, language-support, chinese, kylin

I had reinstall language support , still same issue.
When I add language support chinese, it just hang there(back to language support main screen), and did not ask for sudo password.
  I had install GNOME and ubuntu kylin theme.
  Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try via the terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/locale-langpack/zh_CN
sudo apt install $(check-language-support)
```